# Getting values from point object, that is used as center for a circle object in Java

Tags: java

I've looked around quiet a bit, theres a lot almost like it but they always use variables X1, X2 and Y1 Y2 and im not allowed to do that.
For an assignment I got 2 classes, lets call those A and B

```
    Class A
    //Punt (x,y)
    Punt mp1 = new Punt(1.0, 2.0)
    Punt mp2 = new Punt(3.0, 4.0)

    //Circle(center, radius)
    Circle c1 = new Circle(mp1, 1.0)
    Circle c2 = new Circle(mp1, 1.0)
```

Now in class B i need to see if the circles overlap, so I want to see if distance beweteen centerpoints < radius1 + radius2. I have to public boolean overlap(Circle that)

```
    Class B
    private Punt center
    private double radius
    public Circle(Punt mp, double ra)
        center = mp
        radius = ra

    public boolean overlap(Circle that)
        //here I would need to find the distance between the distance of the centers with Pythagorean theorem
        double sumRadius = this.radius + that.radius  //this one works
    if (distCenter <= sumRadius )
        return true
   else
        return false;
```

Ive tried more than I can think of, but nothing has worked, any tips?

Im not allowed to just make X1 and X2 and create getx1() in class A etc.

Comment: Edit your post to be more clear ... and use a Java syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Circle class surely has getRadius() and getCenter() methods, right? Well get the center values and calculate the euclidean distance, and then compare with the sum of the radii. Actually, you don't even need a getCenter method since you have direct access to the center points, the Punt fields of both Circles, the `this` Circle and the `that` Circle.  Note that Euclidian Distance is the formulas that you've found --

```
Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY)
```

where deltaX is the difference of the two Circle center point X values and likewise for deltaY.

You need to show us your Punt objects. I must assume that you can get the x and y values from them, and therein lies the solution to your problem. i.e. `center.getX()` and `center.getY()`

Comment: I do not have a getRadius() and getCenter() method (Im not even allowed to). The Eucildian Distance I knew, as I am not an English native I've learned this as Pythagoras. About the deltaX and deltaY, thats the whole point, I can't seem go get those X and Y values and I cant subtract Punt objects with this. and that.

Comment: @Zouter: you're not showing us the code for the Punt class, but surely it has methods for extracting its x and y values.

Comment: Of course! I made a punt class for a different assignment. I guess I can use that. Ill go try to work with that and see if it works. I've only been at coding for 3 weeks, excuse me for my ignorance. -- edit it worked with this.center.getX() which was indeed in the Puntclass!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you cant access the variables in the Circle object because those are public. You could create getters or set the correct [visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Then you probably can do something like this:

```
public boolean overlap(Circle other) {
   Punt otherCenter = other.getPunt();
   double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(otherCenter.x - center.x), 2) + 
       Math.pow(Math.abs(otherCenter.y - center.y), 2));

   return distance < ( radius + other.getRadius() );
}
```

I cannot guarantuee this will work, but I think it will point you at the very least to the right direction.